# Delete button in listview Item appears in another position when longclick

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

I'd like to put a delete Button on each on my listview items. This button has to appear when the user longClicks on the textview Inside thelistView Item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edittext"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:inputType="textMultiLine"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:textSize="12dp"
     android:visibility="gone" >

 </EditText>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="14dp" >

 </TextView>

 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/editButton"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
     android:visibility="gone" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code :

```
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           ViewHolder holder = null;

           if (convertView == null) {
               LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
               Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);                
               holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
               holder.button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
               convertView.setTag(holder);

               holder.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {                   
                     public void onClick(View v) { 
                         ListView listView0=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView0);              
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on position : " + listView0.getPositionForView(v),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     } 
               }); 

               holder.text.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
                     public void onClick(View v) { 
                          TextView tv = (TextView) v ; 
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on app : " + tv.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         } 
                }); 


               holder.text.setOnLongClickListener( new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
                     public boolean onLongClick(View v) { 
                          TextView tv = (TextView) v ;
                          ImageButton editButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
                          editButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          editButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
                                 public void onClick(View v) { 
                                      ImageButton iB = (ImageButton) v ; 
                                      ListView listView0=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView0);
                                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleting app : " + listView0.getPositionForView(v),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                      iB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                      }             
                            }); 
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Long Clicked on app : " + tv.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          return true;
                         } 
                }); 
           }
           else {
               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }

           Appreciation currentApp = appList.get(position);
           holder.text.setText(currentApp.getValue());
           holder.button.setTag(currentApp);

           return convertView;

      }
```

My problem : when I longClick on an Item, the delete Button appears on another item ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the id of the view you want appears multiple times in your list, you need to make sure you get the view with that id that appears in the same list item as your TextView.

If you change

```
ImageButton editButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
```

to

```
ImageButton editButton = (ImageButton) ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.editButton);
```

This only searches within the ViewGroup that is the parent of your TextView, so will find the correct instance of R.id.editButton.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you can change

```
ViewHolder holder = null;
```

to

```
final ViewHolder holder;
```

and then you don't need to have your variable `editButton` at all, as you can change the code to

```
holder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and also call `setOnClickListener` on `holder.button` instead of `editButton`. I'd also move the call to `setOnClickListener` outside the `onLongClick` method.

Comment: I tried your update. Works too. But a strange thing, in each of your answer : when I longclick on an item, there are severals delete buttons who appear (not only in the desired item, but in twho or three other ones ...)

Comment: Are these other buttons only after you scroll?  In your `else` branch of the `if (convertView == null)` you need to add `holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. This is because as the views are reused when you scroll, any that have been previously used and had the button made visible will still be visible, so you need to set it back to its original state.

Comment: Yes, there was my problem. Thanks so much :-)